# Generate insert script for some data

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this :

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Age > 5
```

Is there a way to have as result the insert queries ?

The result should like this :

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (.......)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Do something like `select 'INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (' || col1 || ', ' col2 etc...`.

Comment: Or use any of all those tools used to export data.

Comment: Sure about the pipe ? select 'INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (' || Field1|| ','  || Field2 || ')' FROM MyTable give error

Comment: `||` is ANSI SQL for concatenation. Doesn't tsql support it too? Try `+` instead.

Comment: I tried + but didn't work. I use CONCAT should be ok.

Comment: Note that you perhaps have to `cast` non-character columns to char/nchar?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `INSERT . . . SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO mytable ( . . . )  -- list the columns here
    SELECT *   -- you should list the columns here too
    FROM Person
    WHERE Age > 5;
```

Or just create the table, use `INTO`:

```
SELECT p.*
INTO mytable
FROM Person p
WHERE Age > 5;
```

Comment: I know that but I want the script.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a script which iterate throw the current database and create a `SELECT INTO` query for each table inside it. you can filter the query to iterate throw the desired tables or columns, or also you can replace the `EXEC(@selectQuery)` with `Print @selectQuery` to only get the query without executing it.

```
DECLARE @selectQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @tableSchemaName NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @schemaId INT;

DECLARE C CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR(
SELECT schemas.schema_id,
       sys.schemas.name,
       sys.tables.name
FROM sys.tables
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas
        ON schemas.schema_id = TABLES.schema_id);
OPEN C;
FETCH NEXT FROM C
INTO @schemaId,
     @tableSchemaName,
     @tableName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SELECT @columns = STRING_AGG(name, ',')
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE object_id =
    (
        SELECT object_id
        FROM sys.tables
        WHERE name = @tableName
              AND schema_id = @schemaId
    );

    SET @selectQuery
        = N'SELECT ' + @columns + N' INTO ' + @tableSchemaName + N'.' + @tableName + N'2' + N' FROM '
          + @tableSchemaName + N'.' + @tableName;

    EXEC (@selectQuery);
    FETCH NEXT FROM C
    INTO @schemaId,
         @tableSchemaName,
         @tableName;
END;
CLOSE C;
DEALLOCATE C;
```